# Alternative to Activate function in Ext JS 5.1

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a ExtJS menu item for which i have to expand the menu. In Earlier version for ExtJS i used following snippet:

```
`window.c = Ext.getCmp('TabBar:AdminTab');
c.showMenu();
c = Ext.getCmp('TabBar:AdminTab:Admin_UsersAndSecurity');
c.activate()
c.doExpandMenu();
c.deactivate();`
```

But it seems that activate() function is being deprecated. Is there any alternative function for this ?
[image]

> Properties of the Object

[image]

Comment: Did you check extjs 5.1 menu has expand().Check this and reply.

Comment: We don't have expand function for MenuItems. Typically we have doExpandMenu() and Show(), which i have tried.

Comment: Create sample fiddle and show your menu item I will impl code there.

Comment: @Tejas1991. I don't have access to the code. I am using Ext JS to automate the controls on UI. I have attached screenshots which might help you